# Trouble transferring files from Azure Storage Blob to SFTP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have created a xml (for example) in Azure storage and want to upload that to SFTP server directly.

```
string name = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".xml";

        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("xxxxxxxxxxxx");

        // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        //Create reference to a Blob that May or Maynot exist under the container
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);

        // Create or overwrite the "something.xml" blob with contents from a string

        string xml = "some xml";

        blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(xml);

        //Upload file to the sftp server
        string fpath = "https://someazureserver.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxxxxxx/" + name;

        sftp.Connect();
        try
        {
            string INVENTORY = "xxxx/xxxx/xxxx"; //the file path in sftp
            sftp.Put(fpath, INVENTORY);
        }
        finally { sftp.Close(); }
```

I have tried fill out the file path to the url of that blob but that didn't work. I have searched up online but didn't find anything about the path of the blob file. Is there another way to transfer the files from azure to sftp? 
Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the sftp client can retrieve data via http my guess is that the blob is stored in a container that is not configured to allow public access. If you run the code with Fiddler running I am guessing you will see a server authentication error when sftp tries to retrieve the file. If this is the case then you can either provide a SAS token along with the URL that enables access to the file, or you can configure the container to allow public access. See the following articles for more information:

- [Managed access to Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-manage-access-to-resources/)
- [Storage security Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-security-guide/#data-plane-security)

Comment: Ahhhh I just checked microsoft QA, They dont have this feature yet so gg for me. Looks like I have to find another way to do it. Thanks anyway!! I am gonna use ur answer.